# Iterating through key-values in ember.js handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-1

I have a javascript object

```
this.attributes = {
            key: value,
            // etc..
        }
```

I would like to iterate through it and output key:value

Here is my solution:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.attributes = {
        'SKU': '123',
        'UPC': 'ABC',
        'Title': 'Hour Glass'
       }

},

ProductAttributes: Ember.computed('attributes', function() {

    var attribs = this.get('attributes');
    var kvp = Object.keys(attribs).map(key => {
        return {
            'attribute_name': key,
            'attribute_value': attribs[key]
        };
    });
    return kvp;
})});
```

The template I came up with:

```
{{#each ProductAttributes as |attribute|}}
    {{attribute.attribute_name}} : {{attribute.attribute_value}}
{{/each}}
```

I am not happy with this solution since it looks cumbersome: first I convert object into an array of auxiliary objects with non-dynamic keys `attribute_name` and `attribute_value`, and then I references non-dynamic names directly within my template.

It works fine but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can iterate the properties of an object directly with #each-in, `{{#each-in AttributesObject as |key value|}}`

Comment: unfortunately #each-in is not supported by Ember 1.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for this is not that different from the solution you had already described in the question explanation; but my suggestion will provide a you a more reusable and more `each-in` helper-like approach:

How about creating a tagless contextual component with a positional param named `each-in-component` and moving all the computed property definition to that component. I am using kind of Ember 2.x syntax but I guess Ember 1.x will not be very different; so that component will be sth. like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  objectProperties: Ember.computed('object', function() {
    let object = this.get('object');
    return Object.keys(object).map(key => {
        return {
            'key': key,
            'value': Ember.get(object, key)
        };
    });
  }),

  tagName: ''
}).reopenClass({
  positionalParams: ['object']
});
```

and the corresponding component template will be yielding the computed property array:

```
{{#each objectProperties as |objectProperty|}}
    {{yield objectProperty.key objectProperty.value}}
{{/each}}
```

So you can now use that component just like regular `each-in`; which does not exist in Ember 1.x.

```
{{#each-in-component attributes as |key value|}}
    {{key}} : {{value}}<br>
{{/each-in-component}}
```

With this approach; you can re-use the very same component multiple times and the code you did not want to have in your very own component will be lying within `each-in-component`. I have wrapped up my solution to illustrate it in action in the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b06e9c8902c2e0c4127c7c5bf07ca5d2?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2C). I hope it works.